# Organic Simple Configurable Product Prices In Swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, jquery, configurable-swatches

I am currently using Organic Simple Configurable Products extension for Magento CE 1.9.3.2
I have configurable products that are successfully changing the price displayed for the products total price after selecting my options.

I am trying to get the price of a configuration to display in the swatch.

To help understand the question i will give an example scenario.

Say I have a product of T-shirts that have a variation on the Size of Small/Medium which is displayed as a drop down.

I also have a variation of Quantities, 5/10/20 this variation is displayed as a swatch.

example prices:
Small - 5: £10
Small - 10: £18
Small - 20: £34
Medium - 5: £12
Medium - 10: £22
Medium - 20: £40

What I want is for the swatch to display the price when selecting the quantity

eg i have selected small in the size dropdown so the quantity swatches should update to show.

```
5 £10    10 £18    20 £34
```

and if i change the dropdown to medium then the prices in the quantity swatch will change to

```
5 £12    10 £22    20 £40
```

I have spent a lot of time pouring over the code but i haven't got a clue what does what and where and i would appreciate some direction or code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pouring over the code for over 2 days, I have managed to solve it myself. Thought I would provide the result for anyone wanting to do this themselves. (Feel free to show me a simpler way)

First I created a global dropdown attribute called "config_standard_quantity" this i make a swatch by selecting this attribute as a swatch by navigation to:

System > Configuration > Configurable Swatches > General Settings > Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail

Next I wanted the default magento quantity to be hidden if the product being displayed had the attribute "config_standard_quantity" i did this by editing the file

```
app\design\frontend\theme\childTheme\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml
```

find:

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<div class="qty-holder">
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    <div class="qty-changer">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

replace with:

```
<?php if(!$_product->isGrouped() and !$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('config_standard_quantity')): ?>
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<div class="qty-holder">
    <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
    <div class="qty-changer">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

lastly i made changes to the javascript file that make the updates to the prices

```
skin/frontend/base/default/js/scp_product_extension.js
```

before editing copy this file to your active theme then make the following changes.

add the following functions:

```
Product.Config.prototype.getInScopeQtyProductIds = function (optionalAllowedProducts) {
    var childProducts = this.config.childProducts;
    var allowedProducts = [];

    if ((typeof optionalAllowedProducts != 'undefined') && (optionalAllowedProducts.length > 0)) {
        // alert("starting with: " + optionalAllowedProducts.inspect());
        allowedProducts = optionalAllowedProducts;
    }

    for (var s = 0, len = this.settings.length - 2; s <= len; s++) {
        if (this.settings[s].selectedIndex <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        var selected = this.settings[s].options[this.settings[s].selectedIndex];
        if (s == 0 && allowedProducts.length == 0) {
            allowedProducts = selected.config.allowedProducts;
        } else {
            // alert("merging: " + allowedProducts.inspect() + " with: " + selected.config.allowedProducts.inspect());
            allowedProducts = allowedProducts.intersect(selected.config.allowedProducts).uniq();
            // alert("to give: " + allowedProducts.inspect());
        }
    }

    //If we can't find any products (because nothing's been selected most likely)
    //then just use all product ids.
    if ((typeof allowedProducts == 'undefined') || (allowedProducts.length == 0)) {
        productIds = Object.keys(childProducts);
    } else {
        productIds = allowedProducts;
    }
    return productIds;
};

Product.Config.prototype.getQtyOptionCount = function () {
    for (var s = 0, len = this.settings.length - 1; s <= len; s++) {
        if (this.settings[s].config.code == "config_standard_quantity") {
            var data = {count: this.settings[s].config.options.length};
            data["options"] = new Object();
            for (var o = 0, olen = this.settings[s].config.options.length - 1; o <= olen; o++) {
                data["options"][o] = new Object();
                data["options"][o]["label"] = this.settings[s].config.options[o].label;
                data["options"][o]["allowedProducts"] = this.settings[s].config.options[o].products;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
};

Product.Config.prototype.updateSwatchPrice = function (label, price) {
    $$('.option-' + label + ' p').each(function (el) {
        el.innerHTML = label+price;
    });
};
```

Go to function:

```
Product.Config.prototype.reloadPrice = function () {
```

after:

```
var childProductId = this.getMatchingSimpleProduct();
```

paste the following:

```
var qtyProductIds = this.getInScopeQtyProductIds();
var qtyOptionsData = this.getQtyOptionCount();
```

at the end of the function add:

```
if (qtyProductIds.length == qtyOptionsData.count) {
    for (var q in qtyOptionsData.options) {
        for (var p = 0, len = qtyProductIds.length - 1; p <= len; p++) {
            if (Object.values(qtyOptionsData.options[q].allowedProducts).indexOf(qtyProductIds[p]) > -1) {
                var swatchPrice = this.getTaxPrices(childProducts[qtyProductIds[p]]["price"]);
                if (this.taxConfig.showBothPrices) {
                    var str = '<br /><span>' + this.formatPrice(swatchPrice[2], false) + '</span><br /><span class="tax-subclass">' + this.formatPrice(swatchPrice[1], false) + ' ' + this.taxConfig.inclTaxTitle+ '</span>';
                } else {
                    var str = '<br /><span>' + this.formatPrice(swatchPrice[0], false) + '</span><br />';
                }


                this.updateSwatchPrice(qtyOptionsData.options[q].label, str);
            }
        }
    }
}
```